# nftables: how to use 1 common map (or set) for different but related rules? (dnat + forward)

Tags: linux, firewall, nftables

I am setting up a firewall + NAT using `nftables` (v0.9.6). The tool provides sets & maps to avoid a lot of rule duplication.

**I want to use one common data structure (set or map) to configure both DNAT and filtering rules (forward).**

When I try (`nft --check -f example.conf`), I always get an error. Do you know a way to do this **without duplicating** the NAT mapping into 2 data structures (one map & one set)?

Here is the example I use (see UPPERCASE COMMENTS).

These are the **map & set**:

```
table inet filter {
  map mymap {
    type inet_service : ipv4_addr
    elements = {
      12345 : 192.168.0.66,
      4321  : 192.168.0.77
    }
  }

  set myset {
    type ipv4_addr . inet_service
    elements = {
      192.168.0.66 . 12345,
      192.168.0.77 . 4321
    }
  }
```

And these are the **rules**:

```
  chain natprerouting {
    type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; # =-100

    # ACCEPTED:
    dnat ip to tcp dport map @mymap

    # ERROR AT PARSING (unexpected string: @myset):
    dnat ip addr . port to @myset
  }

  chain forward {
    type filter hook forward priority filter; # =0

    # ERROR AT PARSING (unexpected dport):
    ip daddr tcp dport map @mymap accept

    # ACCEPTED:
    ip daddr . tcp dport @myset accept
  }
}
```

It would work if `dnat to` could accept a **set**. Can I convert a **map** into a **set** (or vice versa)? Is there a way?

Comment: coming soon: https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/netfilter-devel/patch/20230512121947.26996-1-fw@strlen.de/

Answer (score 1):

**There is no need to explicitly accept each DNATed connection** in the forward chain, as connection tracking already knows about DNAT.

Just use `ct status dnat accept` like this instead:

```
table inet filter {
  chain forward {
    type filter hook forward priority filter; # =0

    # THIS ONE AUTOMATICALLY ACCEPTS ALL OUR DNATed PACKETS
    ct status dnat accept
  }
}
```

<sub>Some credit goes to [Trent Buck from netfilter mailing list](https://marc.info/?l=netfilter&m=159185780700693).</sub>